# VXML <say-as> within <filled>

Tags: vxml

I recently was able to get `<say-as>` working correctly for my beginning prompt to read of a test number. However, I am now experiencing an issue were `<say-as>` does not seem to process inside a `<filled>` tag.

```
    <form>
    <field name="accountnumber" type="digits?minlength=9;maxlength=9">            
     <prompt>
TEST your account number is 
<say-as interpret-as="number_digit">111111111</say-as>
What is your 9 digit account number
</prompt>       
<filled> 
<prompt> 
<say-as interpret-as="number_digit"> 222222222 </say-as>
</prompt>
</filled>
    </field>
    </form>
```

You can see that I have the same `<say-as>` statement in both the first prompt, and the second prompt. As I would expect the first TTS readoff works as planned, it reads each digit one by one. The second one however does not. It reads off the value as a whole number.

My guess is the following -

1. I need to do something with the field tag
   Or
2. I need to break up the forms somehow.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Robert Second one is read exactly the same way as the first one, and second one is not being taken as a whole number in voxeo. This has something to do with the platform.